Why is my attempt to fit a decay function to my data resulting in a straight line instead of the expected curve?
I am using Python to best fit the data, and I'm trying to fit it against a decay function, and it is producing just a straight line.
Here is my git folder with the data inside of it link. https://github.com/DeAngelo-neutrino/artie
Just download the pythonprogram folder. There are pictures there and you can just ignore them.
The important part of the code is:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import os
import math
import sys
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)


    
os.chdir("/Users/dwooley/Desktop/Python_programs/")


#we need to create varibles that are assoicated with each channel so we can plot, (This has been complete.)
#This creates an array/ column of data
time_argon = np.genfromtxt("log_all_chan_5_10-14_17_44.txt",skip_header=9, delimiter=",", usecols=(0))   
target_top = np.genfromtxt("log_all_chan_5_10-14_17_44.txt",skip_header=9, delimiter=",", usecols=(1))   
target_side = np.genfromtxt("log_all_chan_5_10-14_17_44.txt",skip_header=9, delimiter=",", usecols=(2))   
target_bottom = np.genfromtxt("log_all_chan_5_10-14_17_44.txt",skip_header=9, delimiter=",", usecols=(3))   
front_plate= np.genfromtxt("log_all_chan_5_10-14_17_44.txt",skip_header=9, delimiter=",", usecols=(4))  
N2_level= np.genfromtxt("log_all_chan_5_10-14_17_44.txt",skip_header=9, delimiter=",", usecols=(9))   
 

Here I am just setting up my columns.
Next I create my dataframe in pandas.

df = pd.read_csv("log_all_chan_5_10-14_17_44.txt", skiprows=9, sep=',' ) # we have to use , as delimitter and we use skiprows to ignore the first rows before the data


Then I create a window with 900 objects in it, then take the meaning of it.
window_size = 900 #900 was intial value

time_column = df['Time (s)']
N2_level_dataseries = df['N2 Level']
N2_average = N2_level_dataseries.rolling(window = window_size).mean() #creates an average of 30 ( look up what is a rolling average do?)
#print(time_column)
#print("This is the average with a window of 30" , N2_average)

I then proceed to do some calculations that are irrelevant.
But here they're.
lower = .98 #inches
upper = 4.812 #inches
h_ = upper
R_2 = upper
R_2_cm = 12.22248 #cm
L=67.7 #inches ^2
v_h_0 = 961.4 #inches ^3
R_1 = 4 #inches
R_1_cm = 10.16 #cm
h__lower = R_1
#what is v_R_1
twice_length = 2*L
h_zero = .98 #inches






upper_limitcalculation =   ((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_2*R_2 - h_*h_))*h_) + ((1/2)*R_2*R_2*np.arcsin(h_/R_2))
lower_limit_calculation =   ((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_2*R_2 - h__lower*h__lower))*h__lower) + (1/2)*R_2*R_2*np.arcsin(h__lower/R_2)
full_integration = upper_limitcalculation-lower_limit_calculation

only_R2 =  2*L *full_integration # this is correct we cross check with wolfram and excel
print("only R_2 in integral calculation",only_R2,"inches^3")


# we redefine varibles
h_ = R_1
h__lower =lower
upper_limitcalculation_1 =   ((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_2*R_2 - h_*h_))*h_) + (1/2)*R_2*R_2*np.arcsin(h_/R_2)  #the reason we are getting an error is because of thr R_2^2 - h_ ^2 part this is giving us a negitive number
lower_limit_calculation_1=   ((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_2*R_2 - h__lower*h__lower))*h__lower) + (1/2)*R_2*R_2*np.arcsin(h__lower/R_2)
part_integration_1 = upper_limitcalculation_1-lower_limit_calculation_1


Part_1_volume = 2*L *part_integration_1 
#print(Part_1_volume,"part_1 volume")



h_ = R_1
h__lower =lower
upper_limitcalculation_2 =   ((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_1*R_1 - h_*h_))*h_) + (1/2)*R_1*R_1*np.arcsin(h_/R_1) #the reason we are getting an error is because of thr R_2^2 - h_ ^2 part this is giving us a negitive number
lower_limit_calculation_2=   ((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_1*R_1 - h__lower*h__lower))*h__lower) + (1/2)*R_1*R_1*np.arcsin(h__lower/R_1)
part_integration_2 = upper_limitcalculation_2-lower_limit_calculation_2


Part_2_volume = 2*L *part_integration_2
#print(part_integration_2,"part 2 volme")

I then create my function:
def all_togeterRs(h_n2):
   # h = N2_level
    #now we need to create a equation that takes h as the input
    #the sqrt functinos need to be np and not math.
    return (((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_2**2 - h_n2**2))*h_n2) + ((1/2)*R_2**2 * np.arcsin(h_n2/R_2))) - ((((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_2**2 - h_zero**2))*h_zero) + ((1/2)*R_2**2 * np.arcsin(h_zero/R_2))) )  - ( (((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_1**2 - h_n2**2))*h_n2) + ((1/2)*R_1**2 * np.arcsin(h_n2/R_1))) - (((1/2)* (np.sqrt(R_1**2 - h_zero**2))*h_zero) + ((1/2)*R_1**2 * np.arcsin(h_zero/R_1)))  ) 
#above calculation is in inches


I then add some columns to my existing dataframe.
df['test'] = twice_length * all_togeterRs(N2_average)


#print("hi",new_way.head(50))



df['volume(Argon)'] =  v_h_0+(df['test']) + twice_length*full_integration #this is in inches^3
volume_function_as_height = df['volume(Argon)']

I then parsed the data only selecting a the data set I want
lower_parsed_data = 8000 # this is the lower limit of where the data starts #previous value was 3000, for spline this only works for 7000 to 10000 with window size 900
upper_parsed_data = 10000 #this is the upper limit of where the data ends


data_we_use = volume_function_as_height.iloc[lower_parsed_data:upper_parsed_data]

I then create my expoential decay function
then declare my x and y data
After I have my initial guess for the initial state of the exponential decay.
I proceed to do my curve fit after and plot it
def exponential_decay(x, A, B, C):
    return  A* np.exp(-B * x) + C


x_data = parsed_time_average  
y_data = data_we_use 





initial_guess = [max(y_data),1, min(y_data)]

# Perform the curve fitting
popt, pcov  = curve_fit(exponential_decay, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guess)

# Extract the optimal parameters
A_opt, B_opt, C_opt = popt

# Generate y values using the fitted parameters
y_fit = exponential_decay(x_data, *popt)


# Plot data and fit
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'g-',label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, y_fit, label='Exponential Decay Fit data', color='blue')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
#plt.plot(parsed_time_average,data_we_use, 'r-', label='Original')
plt.title('Exponential Decay Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

And here lies the dilemma my best fit is just producing a straight line, how can I fix this?
I can't upload the picture for some reason, but I've uploaded it on imgur.
Here is the link:
plot of fitted parameters

One of the key things to keep in mind about curve_fit() is that it's very sensitive to initial conditions. This is true to some extent for parameters in your equation like A or C, which linearly affect the result, but it's particularly true for parameters like B, which are fed into a non-linear function.
One of the tools I find useful in this situation is to plot the un-optimized initial guess.

Notice that the blue line is constant. The issue is that for B = 1, the expression np.exp(-B * x) is exactly zero for all X. Because of that, changing B will not help the fit, so the optimizer will not change it at all.
For example,
>>> np.exp(-1 * x_data.values)
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,

...

       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

The curve_fit() function will try both B = 1 and B = 1.0000000149, and determine the slope between them using numerical differentiation. However, the slope is zero, because the np.exp(-B * x) term is zero.
To avoid this, we need to make sure that this term isn't zero. Ideally, it would also be a reasonable guess.
A simple way of doing this would be to pick a smaller initial value of B, like 1e-8. This does converge. But if the data changes, this may no longer be an appropriate initial guess.
A more robust way of finding a good initial value would be to use linear regression. This equation is not linear, but with some small changes, we can make it linear.
Here is how I would change this equation using algebra to make it linear. Note that this isn't Python, this is a mathematical equation/psuedocode.
# starting point
y = A * np.exp(-B * x) + C
# subtract C
y - C = A * np.exp(-B * x)
# take the log of both sides
np.log(y - C) = np.log(A * np.exp(-B * x))
# apply log(a * b) = log(a) + log(b)
np.log(y - C) = np.log(A) * np.log(np.exp(-B * x))
# apply log(exp(a)) = a
np.log(y - C) = np.log(A) * -B * x

This equation means that assuming we have some reasonable guess for C, we can determine a reasonable guess for A and B. Let's turn this equation into Python. We can use scipy.stats.linregress to solve a linear regression.
# This guess can be improved. We'll get back to C_guess.
C_guess = 0
y_data_logged = np.log(y_data - C_guess)
assert np.isfinite(y_data_logged).all()
result = scipy.stats.linregress(x_data, y_data_logged)
A_guess = np.exp(result.intercept)
B_guess = -result.slope

Then, we can plug A_guess, B_guess, and C_guess into exponential_decay(), and look at the resulting plot.

This is close enough that curve_fit() can figure out the rest with this initial guess.
After curve_fit():

Let's return to the subject of C_guess now. I found that many reasonable values worked here. However, values which were closer to C's true value resulted in faster convergence for the other two variables.
The best approach I came up with for finding C is the following:
y_max = y_data.max()
y_min = y_data.min()
y_range = y_max - y_min
C_guess = y_min - y_range

This resulted in the fastest convergence for curve_fit(). It also has some nice theoretical properties: it guarantees that np.log(y - C) is not NaN so long as Y varies.
However, C_guess = y_min / 2 and C_guess = 0 also work.
Appendix: Full Code
This is just the part I changed, without any of the data loading code.
import scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load in the data as x_data and y_data

y_max = y_data.max()
y_min = y_data.min()
y_range = y_max - y_min
C_guess = y_min - y_range

y_data_logged = np.log(y_data - C_guess)
assert np.isfinite(y_data_logged).all()
result = scipy.stats.linregress(x_data, y_data_logged)
A_guess = np.exp(result.intercept)
B_guess = -result.slope


initial_guess = [A_guess, B_guess, C_guess]

# Perform the curve fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponential_decay, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guess)

# Extract the optimal parameters
A_opt, B_opt, C_opt = popt

# Generate y values using the fitted parameters
y_fit = exponential_decay(x_data, *popt)


# Plot data and fit
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'g-',label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, y_fit, label='Exponential Decay Fit data', color='blue')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
#plt.plot(parsed_time_average,data_we_use, 'r-', label='Original')
plt.title('Exponential Decay Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


I used your suggestion of the B value of 1*10**-8 and it worked, thank you so much:)
